# How to pull all alternative tags of a Docker image?

Tags: docker, gitlab, gitlab-ci-runner

I administer a GitLab instance with a build pipeline. All components are encapsulated in Docker images from the official GitLab maintainer.

Whenever I update - usually once a week - I need to check whether the `gitLab/gitlab-runner-helper` still works for the current latest version of GitLab. This can only be checked by executing a pipeline. If it does not work, the log tells me exactly what image it needs an I proceed to pull it.

The image in question is also tagged with a latest tag, which I cannot use, due to the hard dependency to the non-volatile tag.

```
$docker image ls
REPOSITORY                    TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
gitlab/gitlab-runner-helper   x86_64-8af42251     1ee5a99eba5f        20 hours ago        43.7MB
gitlab/gitlab-runner-helper   x86_64-latest       1ee5a99eba5f        20 hours ago        43.7MB
```

**To automate my update process, I'd like to know, how I could pull the latest image with all alternative tags?**

The man page of Docker pull says, there is a `--all-tags` option, to load any tagged image from the repository, but this cannot be combined with a tag.

Comment: Perhaps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28320134/how-to-list-all-tags-for-a-docker-image-on-a-remote-registry has the answer you seek?

Comment: That is unfortunately not the the answer. I am searching for alternative tags of a single image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I posted the [same question at stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52942359/how-to-pull-all-alternative-tags-of-a-docker-image). The question is answered there and I have posted my script. For the sake of completeness, I will post it here as well.

```
#!/bin/sh

TOKEN=`curl -s "https://auth.docker.io/token?service=registry.docker.io&scope=repository:gitlab/gitlab-runner-helper:pull" | jq '.token' | sed 's/"//g'`
TAGS=`curl -s https://registry.hub.docker.com/v2/gitlab/gitlab-runner-helper/tags/list -H "Authorization: Bearer $TOKEN" | jq ".tags[]" | sed 's/"//g' | grep x86_64`

for tag in $TAGS;
do
  # is $tag an old entry?
  if grep -Fxq $tag tags.list
  then
    # already processed
    continue
  else
    echo "new tag found: $tag"
    newSHA=`curl -s https://registry.hub.docker.com/v2/gitlab/gitlab-runner-helper/manifests/$tag -H "Authorization: Bearer $TOKEN" | jq ".fsLayers[] .blobSum" | sed 's/"//g'`
    latestSHA=`curl -s https://registry.hub.docker.com/v2/gitlab/gitlab-runner-helper/manifests/x86_64-latest -H "Authorization: Bearer $TOKEN" | jq ".fsLayers[] .blobSum" | sed 's/"//g'`
    if [ "$newSHA" = "$latestSHA" ]
    then
      echo "$tag is new latest version"
      docker pull gitlab/gitlab-runner-helper:$tag
      echo $tag >> tags.list
    fi
  fi
done
```

The above script utilizes a file named `tags.list`, that is placed next to it. This file contains the older tags, to prevent issuing 500+ HTTP requests. If a tag from the `TAGS` is not yet present in the file, it does not mean, it is the latest. Sometimes tags appear, that eventually will become the latest version. Those tags are probed, but will not be inserted into the file. This might become an issue in the future, if those versions will be skipped as latest.

**Note:** The script above only focuses on a specific subset of tags `(x86_64)`.

Answer (score 0):

You can list all alternative image using the [reg](https://github.com/genuinetools/reg) tool.

Comment: I don't want alternative images. I am searching for alternative tags of a single image.

Comment: you can do it also. you can grep all tags by imagename

Comment: According to their documentation, the list of the tags does NOT include the image hash and is therefore not suitable for my usecase.